# Convert Multiple Rows into One - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, string-aggregation

I'm trying to have the 'test' column in the same row. I'm using `Stuff()` however, it seems that the 'test' column is going through all the qID
What am I missing?

```
SELECT DISTINCT qID,
                STUFF((
                select ',' + B.text
                from tbl B
                where B.qID=qID
                order by B.text
                for xml path('')
                ),1,1,'') as test
FROM tbl 
WHERE qID in (2258060,2296222)
GROUP BY qID
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were missing alias on table

1. Condition B.qID=qID returns always true as if 1=1, it was not doing anything. It was similar to B.qID=B.qID.

By using alias:

```
SELECT DISTINCT qID,
                STUFF((
                select ',' + B.text
                from tbl B
                where B.qID=A.qID
                order by B.text
                for xml path('')
                ),1,1,'') as test
FROM tbl A
WHERE qID in (2258060,2296222)
GROUP BY qID
```

Its also possible without alias on outer query, by using the table name itself.

```
SELECT DISTINCT qID,
                STUFF((
                select ',' + B.text
                from tbl B
                where B.qID=tbl.qID --Table name before qid here 
                order by B.text
                for xml path('')
                ),1,1,'') as test
FROM tbl
WHERE qID in (2258060,2296222)
GROUP BY qID
```

Comment: @DaleK I tested the result using his and mine query.

Comment: Thanks. That did it. Do you know why without the alias it seems to retrieve everything?

Comment: @Camus In your query B.qID=qID returns always true as if 1=1, it was not doing anything. It was similar to B.qID=B.qID.